# Trying to determine what field is referenced in "document.getElementById"

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Migrating a SharePoint site from on-premise 2013 to SharePoint Online. Ran across a page that does not work after migration. Key point is that I cannot figure out what List Column is referenced in document.GetElementByID command in existing code

I know how to determine internal name of field, but not the actual ID.

function PreSaveAction(){

```
disposition = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl32_g_6b054a37_d068_47a5_930e_0789f69b5ab1_ff51_ctl00_DropDownChoice");
if (disposition.options[disposition.selectedIndex].value != "Withdrawn"){
    disposition.options[disposition.selectedIndex].selected = "";
}
for (i=0;i<disposition.options.length;i++){
    if (disposition.options[i].value == "Withdrawn"){
        disposition.options[i].selected = "selected";
    }
}
return true;
```

}

It appears that if I determine the List Column the above is referring to in getElementByID, I need to find the same ID for the List Column in the destination List/Site. I would then update the code to use THAT id.

Just a little lost on how to determine the ID of List Columns.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Where is `List Column` in your code? And what do you mean by determining the id?

Comment: The List Column is what I'm trying to determine in the code provided. It was written by someone else.  It's this line that I'm having trouble with: document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl32_g_6b054a37_d068_47a5_930e_0789f69b5ab1_ff51_ctl00_DropDownChoice");   It appears to be referencing one of the List Columns but I cannot determine which.      Thanks...

Comment: Please post relevant snippets of the HTML too in your question.

Comment: This code is added using the Script Editor Web Part. The page it resides on is a basic List that updates several fields for the selected item when script is run by clicking a button. I don't really have any relevant snippets of HTML to include. 

If I were to summarize my request differently, I would say: Can someone recommend a way to determine what column is being referenced in the above getElementByID? ("ctl00_ctl32.....") 

Thanks...

Comment: I don't think it should be too hard. There are many ways to figure it out, but you should be able to create a new list item, go through the selections (most likely a dropdown) and find where there is a value of "Withdrawn". You then have the column that the code references. F12 on the page, find the element, get the id, replace, save, done.

Answer (score 0):

JS has two method to get element reference, `document.GetElementByID("el_id")` and `document.GetElementByName("el_name")`.  Your tag will look like `<select id="mySelect">` or `<select name="mySelect">`.

Do a search for your id in your main pages and in all the included script files.  If you can't find it, their is two possibility, the id are auto generated by a dev tool or SharePoint and do not match any more or everything is the same and the page did not work in the old environment in the first place witch is often the case.

As a dev guy, you have to remember that everybody lie but computers do exactly what the code says :-)